# How do I get Blogger to show Google+ comments when using Disqus?

Tags: google-plus, blogger, disqus

I have Disqus in the comment section of my blog. I want to show the Disqus comments and Google+ comments together. Is it possible?

In the mobile view I can see the Google+ comments, but not Disqus comments.  In a web browser, I can see Disqus comments, but not Google+ comments.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out

http://www.trackmyblog.com/2013/11/using-googleplus-and-disqus-comment-system-together.html

I used this solution for my own website and it seems to get the job done

Comment: If the link is dead, there will be nothing to check. Please add more info !!

Comment: I fear this has happened...

Comment: Internet archive to the [rescue](https://web.archive.org/web/20140717114522/http://www.trackmyblog.com/2013/11/using-googleplus-and-disqus-comment-system-together.html)